# iterative implementation of the ruler function (1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,...)

Tags: python, algorithm, number-theory

What is an iterative implementation of the [ruler function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RulerFunction.html)?

[This website](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCoroutinesVersusPythonGenerators) asserts that "The ruler function can be generated non-recursively" but never shows an example.

A recursive implementation (from the same webpage) in Python looks like this:

```
def ruler(k):
  for i in range(1, k+1):
    yield i
    for x in ruler(i-1): yield x
```

Comment: I couldn't find this program there. Can you show the exact location? Also, `ruler`'s recursion doesn't have a base case?!?

Comment: @thefourtheye I think the base case is implicit in the call to `range`, since when `i-1` goes to zero you have an empty range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look-up table and bit-twiddling lets you solve this efficiently.

```
ruler = dict((1<<i, i+1) for i in xrange(63))

for i in xrange(1, 20):
    print ruler[i & ~(i-1)],
```

Comment: a lookup table of size O(N) is time-efficient but not space-efficient.

Comment: @JasonS the size of the table is O(log N). The 63 elements in it work for N up to 18446744073709551616.

Comment: oh, OK, somehow I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

For each number `n`, `ruler(n)` is equal to 1 + (number of trailing 0s in binary n).

I think (this untested) it can be implented efficiently as

```
def ruler(n):
    return (x ^ (x - 1)).bit_length()
```

because in binary the tailing digits look like

```
...mno1000    # x
...mno0111    # x - 1
...0001111    # x XOR (x - 1)
```

then you want the number of 1s, which [`.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) gives you.

Comment: Man, awesome :-) How did you get this?

Comment: That's a good hardware approach (I'm aware of the `x^(x-1)` and `x&(x-1)` bit-twiddling hacks) but the `bit_length()` function seems like it's cheating. (maybe not in Python, but in other languages)

Comment: In C, this is just `ffs(n)` which returns the bit position of the least-significant set bit in `n`. (gcc also provides ffsl and ffsll for longer words lengths.)

Answer (score 4):

I may be missing something here, but based on the description of the ruler function...

```
def ruler(k):
    pow = 1
    while ((2*k) % (2**pow)) == 0:
        pow += 1
    return pow-1

for x in range(1, 10):
     print ruler(x)

1
2
1
3
1
2
1
4
1
```

Dunno, maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Exactly. Never recurse when you can loop.

Comment: That only tests one input; ruler(k) in the recursive version is a generator for 2<sup>k</sup> - 1 values.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Hugh Bothwell said, you can do the following (for `n > 0`):

```
def ruler(n):
  return len(bin(n).split('1')[-1]) + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I was trying this prob & use some old methods. Please check it once. I have not set it up totally. But apparently it's working. Few of unfinished broken codes are there.

Apology in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
def ruler():
    print("Initiating ruler function...")
    num = int(input("Enter the value to Eval::  "))

    expNumrange = 1234567890

    if num%2 == 0:
        for i in range(num):
            print(expNumrange,end='----')

    else:
        rem = num%2
        remLen = len(str(abs(rem)))
        expNumrangelen = len(str(abs(expNumrange)))
        finval = len(str(abs(expNumrange - remLen)))
        setVal = expNumrange - finval
        #rem2 = (str(expNumrange) - str(remLen))
        for i in range(num):
            print(expNumrange, end=(str(setVal) + '--'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ruler()
```

Now, please check output.

**For "8"**

```
1234567890----1234567890----1234567890----1234567890----1234567890----1234567890----1234567890----1234567890----
```

**For "5"**

```
12345678901234567880--12345678901234567880--12345678901234567880--12345678901234567880--12345678901234567880--
```